# Change width of Bottom Drawer in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drawer

I've been digging around and can't find a method to modify/contain the width of an imported Material UI Drawer [Swipeable edge](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#swipeable-edge).My idea was that this be of type Bottom but not take up the entire width of the screen.

I was able to change the width of the top with the use of sx. But when it continues to expand, it continues to occupy the entire screen.

Drawer Expanded and unexpanded
[image]

Here is the component code:

```
import "../sheets/Drawer3.module.css";
import "../sheets/Drawer3.css";
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Global } from '@emotion/react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { grey } from '@mui/material/colors';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import SwipeableDrawer from '@mui/material/SwipeableDrawer';

const drawerBleeding = 56;

const Root = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  height: '100%',
  backgroundColor:
    theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? grey[100] : theme.palette.background.default,
}));

const StyledBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '#fff' : grey[800],
}));

const Puller = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: 30,
  height: 6,
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? grey[300] : grey[900],
  borderRadius: 3,
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 8,
  left: 'calc(50% - 15px)',
}));

function Drawer3(props) {
  const { window } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleDrawer = (newOpen) => () => {
    setOpen(newOpen);
  };

  // This is used only for the example
  const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
    <Root >
      <CssBaseline />
      <Global
        styles={{
          '.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root': {
            height: `calc(50% - ${drawerBleeding}px)`,
            overflow: 'visible',
          },
        }}
      />
      <Box sx={{ textAlign: 'center', pt: 1 }}>
        <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(true)}>Open</Button>
        
      </Box>
      <SwipeableDrawer 
        container={container}
        anchor="bottom"
        open={open}
        onClose={toggleDrawer(false)}
        onOpen={toggleDrawer(true)}
        swipeAreaWidth={drawerBleeding}
        disableSwipeToOpen={false}
        ModalProps={{
        keepMounted: true,
        }}
      >
        <StyledBox 
          sx={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: -drawerBleeding,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
            borderTopRightRadius: 10,
            visibility: 'visible',
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            margin: "auto",
            width: 350,
          }}
        >
          <Puller />
          <Typography sx={{ p: 2, color: 'text.secondary' }}>51 results</Typography>
        </StyledBox>
        
      </SwipeableDrawer>
    </Root>
    </div>
  );
}

Drawer3.propTypes = {
  window: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Drawer3;
```

I've looked through the Material Ui documentation and didn't find any props that modify the width. Thank you in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `width` and `left` property inside `Global` as per below code.

```
<Global
  styles={{
    '.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root': {
      height: `calc(50% - ${drawerBleeding}px)`,
      width:350,
      left: `calc(50% - 175px)`,
      overflow: 'visible',
    },
  }}
/>
```